# Javascript: How to extract multiple values from a string using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

My string is like `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?request=516359075128086&to%5B0%5D=100004408050639&to%5B1%5D=1516147434&_=_`

This string is result of a app invitation url redirect request sent to fb.

And what i want to do is, to extract user ids 100004408050639 and 1516147434 to an array.

I tried `var fbCode = testString.match(/to%5B0%5D=(.*)&/);` but this returns only one of these numbers, ie first occurrence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var str = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?request=516359075128086&to%5B0%5D=100004408050639&to%5B1%5D=1516147434&_=_";

var re = new RegExp("to%5B[01]%5D=(\\d+)", "g");
```

When using the `g` modifier for [global search](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp) and want to get matches for a `(` group `)`, could loop through the matches. Those for the first parenthesized group will be in `[1]`

```
var matches = [];

while(matches = re.exec(str)) {
  console.log(matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: This is a neat solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex specifies `%5B0%5D` which translate to `[0]`. The second user ID comes with index 1 (`[1]`) which is encoded as `%5B1%5D`. If you want to accept any (numeric) user-Id-index, use '`/to%5B\d+%5D=(.*?)&/g`' as your regex which allows any number (`\d+`) as well as being global.

Regards.

Comment: I wanted something like Jonny 5's answer. Anyway thanks.